# Accessing Array with for-loop variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I initialized a 2 dimensional array like this:

```
var spielfeld = new Array(400);
for (var i = 0; i < spielfeld.length; i++) {
        spielfeld[i] = new Array(400);
    }
for (var i = 0; i < spielfeld.length; i++) {
    for (var f = 0; f < spielfeld[i].length; f++) {
       spielfeld[i][f] = false;
     }
}
```

Now i want to iterate through it the same way I did in the second part of the inizialisation and check for the content of this. like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < spielfeld.length; i++) {
        for (var f = 0; f < spielfeld[i].length; f++) {
            nachbarn = new Array(8);
            if (spielfeld[i - 1][f - 1] == true) {
            //stuff i wanna do
            }
        }
}
```

But the chrome debugger gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of undefined

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: The very first iteration results in the array being accessed out of bounds. `i` starts at `0`, then you do: `if (spielfeld[i - 1]`.... which tries to access the index of `-1`, which throws an error.

Comment: `spielfeld[-1]` returns `undefined`, and then `undefined[-1]` throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
 for (var i = 1; i <= spielfeld.length; i++) {
       for (var f = 1; f <= spielfeld[i].length; f++) {
         nachbarn = new Array(8);
          if (spielfeld[i - 1][f - 1] == true) {
           //stuff i wanna do
           }
      }
}
```

so you don't have call to `spielfeld[-1][-1]` in first iteration

Comment: but therefore it needs to set the limit higher like: `i <= spielfeld.length` right?

Comment: Yes, fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

`spielfeld[-1]` evaluates to `undefined`, and accessing the `[-1]` of it yields an `Uncaught TypeError`.
The problem with JS is that, unlike Python, [-1] is not wrapped around.